# Was ist das Gegenteil von Kategorie?

Tags: meaning

Wer weiss ein treffendes Wort für das Gegenteil von Kategorie? Es wird gesucht nach einem Wort, dass keine Einschränkungen festlegt.

Comment: Hört sich ein bisschen an wie die Frage nach dem Gegenteil von einer Schublade?

Comment: In welchem Zusammenhang wird das denn benötigt?

Comment: *Kokategorie*  : )

Answer (score 4):

Ein generisches Gegenteil dazu gibt es nicht.

Man kann allenfalls abhängig vom Kontext ein für diesen Kontext passenden Gegenbegriff nehmen.

"Wir kategorisieren die xxxx nicht, sondern beziehen uns auf Alle"

Bei Sportarten, wo die Teilnehmer nicht in bestimmte Kategorien (Klassen) passen, spricht man von einer *offenen Klasse*. *unklassifiziert* ist möglicherweise auch eine Formulierung.

U.U. kann *Obermenge* oder sogar *Oberbegriff* passen, was alle (Unter-)Kategorien umfasst. Noch weiter gefasst, *das Große Ganze*.

*Ganzheit*, *Gesamtheit* oder *in Gänze* könnten u.U. auch passende Formulierungen sein, und nach dem Kategorien nach Differenzen suchen, könnte ein Gegenteil auch auf *Gemeinsamkeiten* beruhen.

Und wer unbedingt nach einem Fremdwort sucht: Ich könnte mir *amorph* als im Sinne von "nicht fassbar" oder "gestaltlos" auch als möglichen Gegenbegriff vorstellen. Wenn man *Kategorien* als Menge von Dingen mit gemeinsamen *Merkmalen* versteht, kann *ohne Berücksichtigung von Merkmalen* möglicherweise auch als Gegenteil dienen.

Wenn ich mir die Schreibtische meiner Kinder anschaue, fällt mir zum Gegenteil von *Schublade* immer *unsortierte Menge* ein :)

Comment: Eine Oberkategorie von PKW wäre Fahrzeug, aber das ist auch wieder eine Kategorie. Vertikal findet man immer Ober- und Unterkategorien.

Comment: Trotzdem ist das "Gegenteil einer bestimmten Fahrzeugkategorie", z.B. PKW, die Menge aller Fahrzeuge und eher nicht die Menge aller Dinge überhaupt.

Comment: Das Gegenteil von heiß ist kalt, aber das Gegenteil von Temperatur gibt es nicht. Das Gegenteil einer bestimmten Temperatur gibt es auch nicht, aber wäre auch nicht unbestimmte Temperatur, auch wenn ein Salat eine bestimmte Temperatur haben kann. Sich einen Salat unbestimmter Temperatur vorzustellen zeigt, dass man das Gegenteil von 'bestimmt' gefunden hat, aber das war halt nicht die Frage.

Comment: Wäre auch eher der Meinung, dass das generische Antonym zu "Kategorie" so nicht existiert. Daher ist das hier schon die beste Antwort, die der Fragensteller kriegen kann, ohne seine Frage zu konkretisieren.

Answer (score 1):

Wie wäre es mit [Gesamtheit](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gesamtheit)?

z.B.

> Ich spreche nicht über eine bestimmte Kategorie von X, sondern alle X in ihrer Gesamtheit.

Da eine Kategorie in den Worten der Mengenlehre als eine unterscheidbare Teilmenge beschrieben werden kann, könnte man in manchen Situationen wohl auch [Gesamtmenge](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gesamtmenge) als Gegenteil verwenden.